# UI Thread stuck for about 4 seconds and dispatcher.BeginInvoke() doesn't solve it

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, ui-thread

In my ListBox, I have over 50 thousands airports listed. When a particular airport is selected, I need to load its runway and other information on the UI. Here is my code:

```
    private void ListAirport_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     ...
              Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
              {
                DataTable dt = TxtFileToTable(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\\r5_IOS.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ListAirport.SelectedItem != null && ListAirport.SelectedItem.ToString() == dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                    {
                        ListRunway.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][1]);
                        ListRunway.SelectedIndex = 0;//select the default runway
                    }
                }
              }
              ));
    }
```

I want to use **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** to avoid the UI getting stuck but it doesn't seem to help. Why and How can I avoid the UI getting stuck? Thanks.

Comment: Well 50.000 items is quite a lot to add to a list... Have you considered [to use data bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547149.aspx) instead of directly populating the controls?

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke won't simply fix your UI lock up. You need to be doing the processing on a background thread and then only passing that information across to the UI thread through the Dispatcher once it is ready to display

Comment: You definitely have no `virtualization` in your list view. It should be enabled by default, but there are many ways to accidently disable it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You definitely shouldn't show 50k items in ListBox. Think about some smarter solution.
2. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` makes your action run on UI-thread. But your handler `ListAirport_SelectedIndexChanged` is already on UI-thread, so you don't have to `BeginInvoke`. Instead of it you should do your hard work in another thread, and show result in UI-thread.

Comment: @mana, can you imagine user, that will read 50k lines of text while searching something? show some mercy:) create some search functionality, or maybe grouping this items in tree-hierarchy can be more comfortable... think up:)

Comment: Oh, the 50k lines are in order of the letters and I have search functionality for that, thank you.@Sam Sch